# Is it possible to delete a record after "return" statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo-12

I made a function in 'hr.contract' that generate a payslip. But this payslip is used to simulate and calculate some salaries, so after create the payslip I must delete it.

Also, I made a function to print the payslip report, from the contract form. The problem is, when I click "print" button I create the payslip and return its report, but then I can't figure out a way to delete the payslip created.

```
def generate_report(self):
        # I get this values from another methods,
        # I put 1 and 20 just to avoid confution in the question.
        run_id = 1
        indicador_id = 20

        payslip = self.generate_fake_nominee(run_id, self.employee_id.id, indicador_id, self.id)

        report = payslip.print_nominee_report()
        return report
```

I can't do stuff after the return, so any ideas?

Comment: The variable `payslip` goes out of scope after `generate_report` returns. Unless `generate_fake_nominee` saves *another* reference to the object, it will be automatically be deleted because `payslip` was the last and only reference to it.

Comment: I've tried setting a new field in contract called 'fake_payslip_id', so when "generate_fake_nominee" is called, the id of "payslip" variable will be saved on that field. But is the same thing, can't print the report if I delete record before returning the report.

Comment: There's not much we can suggest without seeing exactly what `generate_fake_nominee` does.

Comment: @chepner it creates a record in 'hr.payslip'. I have another fuction called "delete_fake_nominee" and make the delete by database. But if I call that function before the return, i get Error to render compiling AST, because record doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Then you need to redesign your (unshown) code so that the report doesn't depend on the record that generated the report.

Comment: yes, I was thinking making a new model, a mirror to 'hr.payslip', in that way I generate the report using the mirror model and I'll not have the need to delete the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `payslip` is the only reference, it should be deleted when the function returns. If it holds resources that might not be cleaned up properly, either:

1. It should implement the context management protocol and a `with` statement could be used:

   ```
   with self.generate_fake_nominee(run_id, self.employee_id.id, indicador_id, self.id) as payslip:
       return payslip.print_nominee_report()
   ```

   or,
2. If you need to call some cleanup function manually, a `finally` block can be used:

   ```
   payslip = self.generate_fake_nominee(run_id, self.employee_id.id, indicador_id, self.id)
   try:
       return payslip.print_nominee_report()
   finally:
       payslip.cleanup_function()
   ```

To be clear, putting `del payslip` in a `finally` block would be completely pointless; the name will be unbound when the function returns anyway, so `del` accomplishes nothing. Either the object bound to `payslip` would be freed anyway (if it had no other aliases) or it wouldn't be free regardless (it's aliased elsewhere). `payslip` is unbound when the function returns no matter what, and all `del` does is make the unbinding explicit, which is slower and pointlessly verbose.

---

**Update:** It seems like the `report` in your original code has a live dependency on the `payslip` object, so you can't actually clean up the `payslip` until the caller is done with the report. If that's the case, you have two options as well:

1. Figure out how to remove the live dependency, so `report` is a standalone set of data (depends on code you haven't shown us, but this is the best solution when possible)
2. Use a finalizer tied to `report` that preserves `payslip` until `report` is garbage collected, at which point it cleans it up, a la:

   ```
   # At top of module
   import weakref

   def generate_report(self):
       # I get this values from another methods,
       # I put 1 and 20 just to avoid confution in the question.
       run_id = 1
       indicador_id = 20

       payslip = self.generate_fake_nominee(run_id, self.employee_id.id, indicador_id, self.id)

       report = payslip.print_nominee_report()
       # Ensure cleanup_function is called when report is gc-ed
       weakref.finalize(report, payslip.cleanup_function)
       return report
   ```

   This option isn't perfect; even on CPython with deterministic reference counting, if a reference cycle gets involved, even when you're done with `report` it can take an arbitrary amount of time before the cycle collector is invoked and `report` actually gets collected (and the cleanup function invoked). On non-CPython interpreters with true garbage collectors, this will happen even without reference cycles.

Comment: I have a function to delete the records, by database query. But still, iI gotta run it before the return, and it don't work.

Comment: I've updated with a solution for what sounds like your problem (`report` having a live dependency on `payslip` that means you can't clean up `payslip` until `report` has been used by the caller).